# Boost library. Jacobian and system setup

Tags: c++, math, boost

Let's assume I have a system of equations:

```
x^2 + y^2 = 1
x - y = 0
```

I want to solve this system by Newton's iterative method: `J(x) * delta_x = -f(x)`
Where J(x) - the Jacobian of this system.

The question is:What is the best way to calculate the Jacobian and set the system?
I have a working version, but it is awkward to set equations and a system in it:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/lu.hpp>
#include <boost/math/differentiation/autodiff.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
using namespace boost::math::differentiation;

template<typename X, typename Y>
promote<X, Y> f0(const X &x, const Y &y) {
    return x * x + y + y - 1;
}

template<typename X, typename Y>
promote<X, Y> f1(const X &x, const Y &y) {
    return x - y;
}

vector<double> f(const vector<double> &var) {
    vector<double> f(2, 0);
    f[0] = f0(var[0], var[1]);
    f[1] = f1(var[0], var[1]);
    return f;
}

matrix<double> J(const vector<double> &var) {
    matrix<double> J(2, 2, 0);
    
    auto const variables = make_ftuple<double, 1, 1>(var[0], var[1]);
    
    auto const &x = std::get<0>(variables);
    auto const &y = std::get<1>(variables);
    
    J(0, 0) = f0(x, y).derivative(1, 0);
    J(0, 1) = f0(x, y).derivative(0, 1);
    J(1, 0) = f1(x, y).derivative(1, 0);
    J(1, 1) = f1(x, y).derivative(0, 1);
    
    return J;
}

int main() {
    vector<double> x(2, 0);
    x[0] = 0.5;
    x[1] = 0.5;
    double eps = 1.e-6;
    int iter = 0;
    
    vector<double> fx, delta_x;
    matrix<double> Jx;
    
    while (iter < 1.e3) {
        Jx = J(x);
        fx = f(x);
        delta_x = -fx;
        // Solve the linear system J(x) * delta_x = -f(x)
        
        permutation_matrix<std::size_t> pm(Jx.size1());
        lu_factorize(Jx, pm);
        lu_substitute(Jx, pm, delta_x);
        
        x += delta_x;
        if (norm_2(delta_x) < eps) break;
        
        if (++iter % 10 == 0)
            std::cout << "[" << iter << "] " << "Solution: " << x << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Final answer:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[" << iter << "] " << "Solution: " << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You already have to do a lot of problem-dependent work in specifying the equations of your system. I appreciate that you can have a lot of variables, but if you can write the individual equations in code then you can do the same with the Jacobian. A bigger problem is probably the fact that Newton-Raphson can fail and the challenge of setting a good initial guess. For example, your system example has two solutions (1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)) and (-1/sqrt(2),-1/sqrt(2)), but if you start with initial guess (0,0) then it will fail at the first step.

Comment: Interesting question; can you clarify what your task is here? I mean, is the goal to solve the equations, or is the goal to use Boost to solve the equations? If you don't have to use Boost, there are other (simpler) ways to go about implementing Newton's method, but maybe you are required to use Boost.

Comment: @RobertDodier The way I read it, it probably isn't about solving the particular example, but rather how to use the Boost interfaces in a way that is less clumsy/tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you didn't really explain **what** is "awkward" about the code.

I looked at it for a bit and was able to come up with some optimizations and simplifications (e.g. using C++17 language features).

> Note, for clarity (and safety) I use namespace aliases:
>
> ```
> namespace U = boost::numeric::ublas;
> namespace D = boost::math::differentiation;
> ```

The optimizations is to avoid unbounded array storage for vectors/matrices because they are fixed size:

```
template <size_t N, typename T = double> using FixedVector = U::vector<T, std::array<T, N>>;
using Vec = FixedVector<2>;
using Mat = U::matrix<double, U::row_major, std::array<double, 4>>;
```

I opted for `std::array` because it's trivial and constexpr friendly, and (contrary to `U::bounded_array<>`) allows initializer-list construction. This will allow us more natural assignments:

```
Vec f(Vec const& var) {
    auto& [x, y] = var.data();
    return Vec(2, {f0(x, y), f1(x, y)});
}

Mat J(Vec const& var) {
    auto const& [x, y] = D::make_ftuple<double, 1, 1>(var[0], var[1]);
    return Mat{2, 2,
        {
            f0(x, y).derivative(1, 0),
            f0(x, y).derivative(0, 1),
            f1(x, y).derivative(1, 0),
            f1(x, y).derivative(0, 1),
        }};
}
```

The other part is to use structed bindings instead of the `get<n>` or `[n]` dances.

> Looking at this from an efficiency standpoint, I'd verify that the compiler eliminates the common subexpressions in the matrix initializers.

For the `f0`/`f1` functions I've let type deduction do the work:

```
constexpr auto f0(auto const& x, auto const& y) { return x * x + y + y - 1; }
constexpr auto f1(auto const& x, auto const& y) { return x - y; }
```

The main driver hasn't changed much, though I reshaped the loop so it's more conventional:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dbfa3e969bd47c7)**

```cpp
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/lu.hpp>
#include <boost/math/differentiation/autodiff.hpp>

constexpr auto f0(auto const& x, auto const& y) { return x * x + y + y - 1; }
constexpr auto f1(auto const& x, auto const& y) { return x - y; }

namespace U = boost::numeric::ublas;
namespace D = boost::math::differentiation;

template <size_t N, typename T = double> using FixedVector = U::vector<T, std::array<T, N>>;
using Vec = FixedVector<2>;
using Mat = U::matrix<double, U::row_major, std::array<double, 4>>;

Vec f(Vec const& var) {
    auto& [x, y] = var.data();
    return Vec(2, {f0(x, y), f1(x, y)});
}

Mat J(Vec const& var) {
    auto const& [x, y] = D::make_ftuple<double, 1, 1>(var[0], var[1]);
    return Mat{2, 2,
        {
            f0(x, y).derivative(1, 0),
            f0(x, y).derivative(0, 1),
            f1(x, y).derivative(1, 0),
            f1(x, y).derivative(0, 1),
        }};
}

int main() {
    constexpr double eps  = 1.e-6;
    Vec x(2, {0.5, 0.5});

    U::vector<double> fx, delta_x;
    U::matrix<double> Jx;

    for (auto iteration = 0; iteration < 1'000; ++iteration) {
        Jx      = J(x);
        fx      = f(x);
        delta_x = -fx;
        // Solve the linear system J(x) * delta_x = -f(x)

        U::permutation_matrix<std::size_t> pm(Jx.size1());
        lu_factorize(Jx, pm);
        lu_substitute(Jx, pm, delta_x);
        
        x += delta_x;
        std::cout << "[" << iteration << "] Solution: " << x << std::endl;

        if (norm_2(delta_x) < eps)
            break;
    }
    std::cout << "Solution: " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Printing

```
[0] Solution: [2](0.416667,0.416667)
[1] Solution: [2](0.414216,0.414216)
[2] Solution: [2](0.414214,0.414214)
[3] Solution: [2](0.414214,0.414214)
Solution: [2](0.414214,0.414214)
```

### Summary

I expect the changes to make the code marginally faster (it'd be interesting to see a micro-benchmark without the I/O).

I'm not sure whether any of this addressed some of the "awkwardness" that you were referring to in the question.

Comment: Oh as an afterthought, here a pure [c++17 version](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e40bdaddfe2c99b), [c++14 version](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b3c2c1d042efe8e) or even [c++11 version](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0576cdd21a77c2cc) (though note that since Boost 1.82 Boost.Math dropped official support for that).

Comment: I didn't like the separate declaration of functions f0, f1. I wanted to expand the case to a large number of variables with minimal changes in the code. For example, make functions f an array, and set, for example, 20 functions. Next, the Jacobian would be automatically counted for 20 functions with 20 variables (2 the unpleasant place is that "promote" would be huge).

But I really liked your code improvement, you used constructs that I hadn't seen before. I am very grateful that you showed them =)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could avoid boost and just roll your own.

Equations set up using functional. Jacobians worked out by finite differences for generality, but could do with improvement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

using FUNC = function< double( vector<double> ) >;         // double-valued function with vector argument

bool solve( vector<FUNC> eqns, vector<double> &x );
vector<double> operator -( vector<double> a, const vector<double> &b );
vector<double> getFunction( vector<FUNC> eqns, const vector<double> &x );
vector< vector<double> > getJacobian( vector<FUNC> eqns, const vector<double> &x );
double getResiduals( const vector<double> &f );
bool GaussElimination( vector< vector<double> > A, vector<double> B , vector<double> &X );

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   vector<FUNC> eqns = {                                                  // equations to be solved
      []( vector<double> x ){ return x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1] - 1; },
      []( vector<double> x ){ return x[0] - x[1];                   }
                       };
   vector<double> x = { 1.0, 1.0 };                                       // initial guess (gives positive root)
// vector<double> x = {-1.0,-1.0 };                                       // alternative (gives negative root)

   if ( solve( eqns, x ) )
   {
      for ( auto e : x ) cout << e << '\n';
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Failed\n";
   }
}

//======================================================================

bool solve( vector<FUNC> eqns, vector<double> &x )
{
   const int MAXITER = 1000;
   const double TOL = 1.0e-6;
   double residuals = 1.0;
   for ( int iter = 1; iter <= MAXITER && residuals > TOL; iter++ )
   {
      auto f = getFunction( eqns, x );                       // compute f(x*)
      if ( residuals < TOL ) break;                          // if converged, finish

      auto J = getJacobian( eqns, x );                       // computed J(x*)
      vector<double> deltax( x.size() );
      if ( !GaussElimination( J, f, deltax ) ) break;        // update x -> x* - J^-1.f(x*)
      x = x - deltax;                                        //

      residuals = getResiduals( f );                         // test for convergence
   }
   return residuals <= TOL;
}

//======================================================================

vector<double> operator -( vector<double> a, const vector<double> &b )         // utility routine to subtract vectors
{
   for ( int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++ ) a[i] -= b[i];
   return a;
}

//======================================================================

vector<double> getFunction( vector<FUNC> eqns, const vector<double> &x )       // fill in current function values
{
   vector<double> f;
   for ( FUNC e : eqns ) f.push_back( e( x ) );
   return f;
}

//======================================================================

vector< vector<double> > getJacobian( vector<FUNC> eqns, const vector<double> &x )   // create Jacobian from FINITE DIFFERENCES
{
   const double SMALL = 1.0e-6;                                                      // needs improving for generality
   int N = x.size();
   vector< vector<double> > J( N, vector<double>( N ) );
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
      {
         auto xplus  = x;   xplus [j] = x[j] + 0.5 * SMALL;
         auto xminus = x;   xminus[j] = x[j] - 0.5 * SMALL;
         J[i][j] = ( eqns[i]( xplus ) - eqns[i]( xminus ) ) / SMALL;                 // finite-difference approximation for df_i/dx_j
      }
   }
   return J;
}

//======================================================================

double getResiduals( const vector<double> &x )                                       // L2 norm of vector x
{
   double res = 0.0;
   for ( auto e : x ) res += e * e;
   return sqrt( res );
}

//======================================================================

bool GaussElimination( vector< vector<double> > A, vector<double> B , vector<double> &X )
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Solve AX = B by Gaussian elimination
// Note: copies made of A and B
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
{
   const double SMALL = 1.0e-20;
   int n = A.size();

   // Row operations for i = 0, ,,,, n - 2 (n-1 not needed)
   for ( int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ )
   {
      // Pivot: find row r below with largest element in column i
      int r = i;
      double maxA = abs( A[i][i] );
      for ( int k = i + 1; k < n; k++ )
      {
         double val = abs( A[k][i] );
         if ( val > maxA )
         {
            r = k;
            maxA = val;
         }
      }
      if ( r != i )
      {
         for ( int j = i; j < n; j++ ) swap( A[i][j], A[r][j] );
         swap( B[i], B[r] );
      }

      // Row operations to make upper-triangular
      double pivot = A[i][i];
      if ( abs( pivot ) < SMALL ) return false;            // Singular matrix

      for ( int r = i + 1; r < n; r++ )                    // On lower rows
      {
         double multiple = A[r][i] / pivot;                // Multiple of row i to clear element in ith column
         for ( int j = i; j < n; j++ ) A[r][j] -= multiple * A[i][j];
         B[r] -= multiple * B[i];
      }
   }

   // Check last row
   if ( abs( A[n-1][n-1] ) < SMALL ) return false;         // Singular matrix

   // Back-substitute
   X = B;
   for ( int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
   {
      for ( int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )  X[i] -= A[i][j] * X[j];
      X[i] /= A[i][i];
   }

   return true;
}
```

Output:

```
0.707107
0.707107
```

Comment: Very nice work. Awesome really. There is a problem with SMALL (1e-20 is below epsilon for `double`, which is only 2.22e-16). It is even below epsilon for long double (1.08e-19 on my system).

Comment: There's also a bit of gain to be had with small tweaks: making arguments `const&` and avoiding `std::function`'s type erasure. If you go a little further to avoid dynamic allocation (templating the implementation on `N`) you get a much better performance improvement: see _`tweaked` (1.6x) and `improved` (7.7x)_ in [this benchmark code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71fc064bace50a84): https://i.imgur.com/kdmlCz4.png

Comment: Thank-you, @sehe. SMALL in the matrix solver is probably too small(!) as you say, but that is where a library routine would be used anyway. The SMALL in the Jacobians routine is more bothersome: it’s fine if the variable range is O(1), but not if it is O(1e-10) or O(1e10). I’ve never quite found a robust answer to this (other than preferring to work with dimensionless variables, which are O(1) by construction).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the best way to get to a "domain relative epsilon" is by extrapolating from [`std::nextafter[f]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) and friends. Indeed, using some kind of arbitrary/high precision real number type kills performance really hard: [code with `cpp_bin_float` added](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdd7385bc0948012) Comparison chart https://i.imgur.com/uRqSlAH.png